# Random number frequencies

Tags: java

I have created a array consisting of 6 numbers, and I randomly print the contents 100 times (to simulate rolling a dice 100 times). Now I want to show the frequencies of each number printed, which I am having trouble with. Any help would be appreciated.
What I have already done:

```
        int dice;

    int[] diceArray = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

    Random rand = new Random();

    for (int counter = 0; counter < 100; counter++) {
        dice = diceArray[rand.nextInt(diceArray.length)];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to have a separate array with the frequencies:

```
int[] frequencies = new int[6];

for (int counter = 0; counter < 100; counter++) {
  int index = rand.nextInt(diceArray.length);
  dice = diceArray[index];
  frequencies[index]++;
}
```

Comment: And then something like:
 for(int i = 0;i < frequencies.length;i++)
    System.out.println("Value: " + (i + 1) + " result: " + dices[i]);

Answer (score 0):

```
 Int[] cnt= new int[6]; // Counter for each dice-roll
 for (int i = 0; i<6;i++) cnt[i] = 0; // Make everyone 0
 Random random = new Random(); // To get random numbers
 for (int i = 0; i<100;i++){ // To roll 100 times
      int a = random.nextInt(6 - 1 + 1); // Save your dice Roll
      cnt[a-1]+=1; // to log your frequencies
      System.out.println(a) // to print out
}
```

Did not try this, and it's been a while i have been using java, but this should be working. I am sorry if it's not!